# I have trouble to display images on my admin page

Tags: database, bubble.io

I’ve built two separate page, one for the user to upload his picture, and the other for the admin to verify this picture. But when the picture is uploaded by the user, it is not displayed in the admin page.
PS: The data fields and data sources in the reaping group and picture uploader group I believe they’re correctly set up. I don’t know if there is something to fix in the workflow or it has to do with admin access setup. Please help me guys, I’ve been wrestling with this issue for over a week now.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P977T.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqxzb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaK4O.jpg)

I’ve built two separate page, one for the user to upload his picture, and the other for the admin to verify this picture. But when the picture is uploaded by the user, it is not displayed in the admin page.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Meayq.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSCYd.jpg)